# Can not override a variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, mvvm

For example, I created base classes for all the views of my project used MVVM pattern, and it hasn't any problem yet.

```
class BaseView: UIView {
    var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol

    init(viewModel: ViewModelProtocol) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel

        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
}


protocol ViewModelProtocol {
}

class BaseViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
}
```

However, If I create a child class(`CustomView`) inherited from parent class(`BaseView`) and it has to have a seperate ViewModel(`CustomViewModel`), I will get an error `Property 'viewModel' with type 'CustomViewModel' cannot override a property with type 'ViewModelProtocol'` at `override var viewModel: CustomViewModel` line.

```
final class CustomView: BaseView {
    override var viewModel: CustomViewModel
}


final class CustomViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

        super.init()
    }
}
```

How can I do to meet the following conditions below?

1. Every custom views should have to inherit `BaseView`.
2. `BaseView` should have `BaseViewModel`.
3. Every custom views can have a custom view model inherited from `BaseViewModel`.

Comment: You're breaking the Liskov substitution principle. See https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making `BaseView` accept generic `ViewModel` as below so that you don't need to `override` the `viewModel` property and your `viewModel` will always be the same custom type provided while inheriting from `BaseView`.

```
class BaseView<ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol>: UIView {
    var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel

        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
}

final class CustomView: BaseView<CustomViewModel> {

     // viewModel is of type  'CustomViewModel'
}
```